# Name for hair-washing spray comb thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

What’s the proper name for the gadget used in salons to wash hair?  Picture a comb with a hose on it, maybe a strap for the hand.  Water comes out very gently across the face, not really a *spray* at all.

If it doesn’t have a distinct term in the industry, what would be a good name for it?

---

To clarify: suppose a spa has several “regular” un-dockable shower heads (e.g. [Waterpick Elite](https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/waterpik-reg-elite-trade-shower-massage-plus-8-mode-handheld-showerhead/1017626795?categoryId=13481)) *and* **one** like I described. What does a word-concious person call the special one?

It doesn’t (in normal use) [spray](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spray). Rather, the water runs gently (ooze, soak, seep).

Comment: Salon shower heads? I have never seen one that includes a comb. Although there is a patent for a water comb http://www.google.com/patents/US6244273

Comment: I'd call it a "dog washer".

Comment: I don't think I've seen one with a built in comb either (that does sound more like a pet grooming product), but are you thinking of a **hand spray**?  eg https://www.directsalonfurniture.co.uk/backwash-units/rem-handspray-hose/?attribute_type=Handspray%20And%20Hose%20With%20Basin%20Sleeve%20Kit&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_LGTrY_11gIViL3tCh1-QgC5EAQYBSABEgJiBfD_BwE

Comment: @MaxWilliams not just any sprayer on a hose, like in your kitchen.  It specifically is for hair. The name would distinguish it from the regular sprayers.

Comment: The one I linked to **is** for hairdressers.

Comment: @MaxWilliams To me, the picture looked like a bathroom spigot that can pull out like the popular kitchen sprayers that are the same head as the regular faucet.

Comment: @JDługosz well, they do serve a very similar function, so it makes sense that they would look somewhat alike.

Comment: The intensity of the spray (water pressure) is likely to be variable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for specialized industry-specific terminology.